# store the output of shift register in RAM in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am writing a code to shift 128bit register 25 position then store the first 96 bit of it in RAM (mem_bank width in RAM = 16 bit), i try to decleare a counter to do the shift in the first clock cycle and store sub values in RAM for the next 6 (96/16) cycles.  i use the counter for indexing but i have a proplem that counter is not constant ??? here is the code for RAM

```
module RAM(clk,we,din,dout,address);
input clk,we,re;
input [15:0] din;
input [5:0] address;
output [15:0] dout;

reg [15:0] dout;
reg [15:0] mem_bank [0:51];
integer i;
initial 
begin
    for (i=0;i<52;i=i+1)
    mem_bank[i] <=0;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin 
if(we)
    mem_bank[address] <= din;
dout <= mem_bank[address];
end
endmodule
```

and this is the code for shift register

```
module keygen(clk,load,data0,data1,data2,data3,out1,out0);
input clk,load;
input [31:0] data0,data1,data2,data3;
output [31:0] out1,out0;
reg [127:0] reg128;
integer adrs = 0;  //address of RAM from 0 to 51
integer count=0;
parameter KEYSIZE = 16;
integer lowindex=0;
integer highindex=0;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
if(load)
    reg128 <= {data3,data2,data1,data0};
else if(count < 1)
begin

    reg128 [127:25] <= reg128 [102:0];
    reg128 [24:0] <= reg128 [127:103];
    count =count + 1;       
end
else if(count <8 && adrs < 52)
begin 
//  lowindex= (count-2)*KEYSIZE;
//  highindex = (count-2)*KEYSIZE+KEYSIZE-1;
RAM ram(.clk(clk),.we(1),.din(reg128[(count-2)*KEYSIZE:(count-2)*KEYSIZE+KEYSIZE-1]),.address(adrs));
adrs=adrs+1;
if (count < 8)
count =count + 1;       
else
count = 0;
end
end
assign out0=reg128[31:0];
assign out1=reg128[63:32];
//assign out2=reg128[95:64];
//assign out3=reg128[127:96];

endmodule
```

any help please to fix this

Comment: What is your problem exactly? If it's an error message please post the exact text of the error. Also I don't think you should be instantiating a module (RAM) inside an if block, that makes no sense logically.

Comment: Verilog has a shift operator: `{reg128,blank} <= {reg128,reg128} << 25;`

Comment: the error message "count is not a constant",

Answer (score 1):

First off, you've a RAM instantiation inside an `always` block. This is bad - move it outside. And use nonblocking assignments for your counter updates (`<=`).

To fix your other problem, use "indexed part selects". For your problem, I'd try rewriting

```
reg128[(count-2)*KEYSIZE:(count-2)*KEYSIZE+KEYSIZE-1]
```

as

```
reg128[(count-2)*KEYSIZE+KEYSIZE-1 -: KEYSIZE ];
```

Traditionally, for part-selects in verilog (for example `reg_a[3:4]`), the limits have to be constant. In more recent versions of verilog, there's new "index part selects", which allow you to vary one of the dimensions. Its in the form `reg_a[START +: WIDTH]`, so `reg_a[3 +: 4]` is the same as `reg_a[3:6]` - 4 bits starting from index 3. The START can vary here, but the width has to stay constant.

Another variant, `reg_a[3 -: 4]` will give you `reg_a[3:0]`.

Comment: if i move RAM out of always how can i check if the address reach 52?

Comment: Well, where are you driving the address from? The address isn't an output of the RAM model, so maybe you're missing a bit of code?